# Soap Calls fails while Connecting to my asmx service from the Android application

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to call a Login service from my android application . The Web Service is created in asmx (its a simple web service which has imported some oracle libraries and interface the oracle database). When I test the asmx service as a stand alone by feeding values through the web it works fine. However when I try to connect and call the Login service from my android application , it fails with the following error

---

SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'OracleDbLib2010, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
The relevant code which is calling this service is as follows

---

```
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://test.app.org/";;
public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "Login"; 
public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://test.app.org/";
public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "https://abc.test.com/ws/webservice/Service1.asmx"; 
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("name");
pi.setValue(name);
pi.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(pi);
pi=new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("password");
pi.setValue(password);
pi.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(pi);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
Object response=null;
try
{
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+OPERATION_NAME, envelope);
response = envelope.getResponse();
}
```

Comment: Looks like the error is server side, can you confirm if other platforms can connect correctly?

Comment: I am debugging this. Can you tell me how to put log statments in my asmx file that would be printed using logcat when I run my Android application